# PHP: array_rand arrays

Tags: php, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

I have this array:

```
$nonTerminals = array("S","A","B");
$grammar = array(
"$nonTerminals[0]" => "aA",
"$nonTerminals[1]" => array("aA","bB"),
"$nonTerminals[2]" => array("bB","b")
);
```

and I use this for random values:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($grammar, 2);
echo $grammar[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
```

But this is wrong, because it's give me some errors.

Comment: Can you post the errors you get? Because now, from what I see, you are trying to echo an array..

Comment: And those errors are?

Comment: If the second or third are chosen you're trying to echo an array, probably `Notice: Array to string conversion`.

Comment: Use `var_dump` instead of `echo` so you can print the contents of the arrays.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/8vnrsx

Comment: well i need a random value from here:
"$nonTerminals[1]" => array("aA","bB").
i need or "aA" or "bB".
How can i get it ?

Comment: You can't echo an array. You'll have to use print_r or var_dump instead.

Comment: @adyadryan How do you decide whether to print `aA` or `bB`?

Comment: You can get a random value if you would use "echo $grammar[$rand_keys[0]][rand(0,1)] . "\n";" but this will only work if the value in "$grammar[$rand_keys[0]]" is an array. This you can check by using "is_array($grammar[$rand_keys[0]])

Comment: BTW, you should write `$nonTerminals[0] => `, not `"$nonTerminals[0]" =>`. You don't need to put a string variable in quotes.

Comment: well, i tried with array_rand() to get aA or bB...but it doesn't work. and i don't know how make it

Comment: i think that this one $grammar[$rand_keys[0]][rand(0,1)] solved my problem. thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$nonTerminals = array("S","A","B");
$grammar = array(
"$nonTerminals[0]" => "aA",
"$nonTerminals[1]" => array("aA","bB"),
"$nonTerminals[2]" => array("bB","b")
);

$rand_keys = array_rand($grammar, 2);
if (!is_array($grammar[$rand_keys[0]]) {
    //This checks if the value is an array or not.
    echo $grammar[$rand_keys[0]];
}
else {
    //it is an array, so echo a random value from that array;
    echo $grammar[$rand_keys[0]][rand(0, 1)];
}
```

Comment: No problem :-) Don't forget to accept the answer ;)